# What is a "charged order parameter"?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, phase-transition

In condensed matter physics, especially in the context of superconductors, if an author uses the phrase ["charged order parameter"](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=charged+order+parameter), what does it refer to? Since the superconductor has a close relation with high energy physics, I think it may come from quantum field theory.

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Well, it is just a condensate made with charges. The order parameter is the density of 2-electrons correlations (often called Cooper pairs). Since it's charged, it has characteristic properties, like the  magnetic vortex quantisation at high magnetic field (and the associated pseudo-levitation), the perfect diamagnetism at low magnetic field, the Little-Parks effect, the Josephson effect and the associated SQUIDs and qubits, the London momentum effect (also called rotating superconductor effect), and so on. For more details check for the above effects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes,I should regrad cooper pairs as "charged order parameter".Maybe I lost something important ,I should come back to my textbook again.